# React Highcharts v9.2 Solid Gauge Rounded Ends

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I am working with solid gauge. We are upgrading from version 7.2.2 to the latest 9.2. We use to be able to pass in the y-axis plotbands a rounded: true which would round the tips of the bands. Since upgrading this no longer works. Instead the tips are squared off. I am looking for any assistance in how I might handle this.

Here is a fiddle of what it looks like squared off:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w9mfx87g/7/)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

chart: {
    type: 'solidgauge',
    height: '110%',
},

tooltip: {
    borderWidth: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'none',
    shadow: false,
    style: {
        fontSize: '16px'
    },
    valueSuffix: '%',
    pointFormat: '{series.name}<br><span style="font-size:2em; color: {point.color}; font-weight: bold">{point.y}</span>',
    positioner: function (labelWidth) {
        return {
            x: (this.chart.chartWidth - labelWidth) / 2,
            y: (this.chart.plotHeight / 2) + 15
        };
    }
},

pane: [
{
    "startAngle": -140,
    "endAngle": 140,
    "background": {
        "shape": "arc",
        "borderWidth": 0,
        "backgroundColor": "#FFF0"
    }
}
  ],

yAxis: [
{
    "gridLineWidth": 0,
    "opposite": false,
    "title": {
        "text": "",
        "useHTML": true
    },
    "labels": {
        "useHTML": true,
        "format": "{value}",
        "enabled": false
    },
    "min": 0,
    "max": 100,
    "lineWidth": 0,
    "tickWidth": 0,
    "minorTickWidth": 0,
    "plotBands": [
        {
            "thickness": "10%",
            rounded: true,
            "from": 0,
            "to": 73,
            "color": "#1792E555",
        },
        {
            "thickness": "10%",
            "from": 76,
            "to": 88,
            "color": "#FFE393"
        },
        {
            "thickness": "10%",
            "from": 91,
            "to": 100,
            "color": "#F9B890"
        }
    ],
    "plotLines": [],
    "index": 0
}
],

plotOptions: {
    solidgauge: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        linecap: 'round',
        stickyTracking: false,
        rounded: true
    }
},

series: [
{
    "data": [
        {
            "y": 10,
            "color": "#1792E5"
        }
    ],
    "radius": "100%",
    "innerRadius": "90%",
    linecap: 'rounded',
    "rounded": true,
    "useDial": false,
    "type": "solidgauge",
    "tooltip": {
        "enabled": true,
        "useHTML": true,
        "borderRadius": 0,
        "borderWidth": 0,
        "shadow": false,
        "valueDecimals": 2,
        "style": {
            "fontFamily": "inherit"
        },
        "padding": 6,
        "shape": "square"
    },
    "dataLabels": {
        "style": {
            "textOutline": "none"
        }
    },
    "events": {}
}
]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not so easy to do. Since the plotBand is an SVG element you can try to edit its path and round the corners but it might be hard. You can check how the rounded path is created here: https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.src.js?_ga=2.104350400.154582566.1629699669-527407293.1629434064

And you can also check out this plugin: https://github.com/highcharts/rounded-corners

But the easiest solution would be to use another solidGauge series instead of plotBand. Something like that: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k35vcsnx/

```
series[{...}, {
 type: "solidgauge",
 rounded: true,
 data: [{
  color: "#1792E555",
  radius: '100%%',
  innerRadius: '90%',
  y: 73
 }]
}
```

Comment: The first one seems to be the best option unfortunately. Do you know how to do your 3rd option if using multiple bands similar to my fiddle?

I appreciate the help. If the 3rd option is available that is great. I will mark this as an approved answer as we can always make a custom extension (though not ideal...highcharts should have this built in since it is a paid library and it use to work).

Comment: As far as I see if you use multiple series to create something like plotBands from yAxis the color gets mixed. A possible solution to that could be using yAxis.stops which allow us to color the points separately depending on their value. POC: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d8b4eja1/